# Can the verb "intake" be used intransitively?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech, transitivity

Can a combustion engine be said to *intake* oxygen?

Comment: What did your dictionary search show?

Comment: [nothing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intake#Verb)

Comment: I am a bit confused. In "to intake oxygen", *intake* is obviously being used transitively, not intransitively.

Comment: Except for technical contexts, I don't see why anybody should use the verb "intake" rather than "take in". For one thing, the past tense, "intook", almost never used. is The noun "intake" and the adjective "intaken" are a different matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warm_air_intake):

> The net effect is for the engine to **intake** the same amount of oxygen …  [emphasis mine]

Yes, in technical writing, words assume all kinds of POSs depending on usage within the domain. Do not try to compare such usage in one domain to another.

*Intake* in the above context means what it does in that context (perform the act of taking in air for combustion in the IC engine) and the usage is strictly limited to that context.

Comment: POS? Can the verb be used transitively in general or not?

Comment: POS: Part of speech. No, do not use *intake* as *vt* in general English writing. Your question is focused on the domain of internal combustion engines, not general English writing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your question.

1. "intake" is not a verb to begin with.
2. Even if it is a verb, in your example "intake oxygen", as it is followed by an object, it would be a transitive verb, not intransitive.

Perhaps you meant to say "the engine takes in oxygen" or "the engine consumes oxygen", etc.

Comment: I meant "transitive", that's right. but it is a verb.